# Speeding Magento 2

Tags: pagespeed, speedoptimization

I am running a magento 2.4.5 in production mode

The settings in admin are as follows:

Minify Html: Yes

Merge JavaScript Files: Yes

Enable JavaScript Bundling: Yes
Minify JavaScript Files: Yes

Merge CSS Files: Yes

Minify CSS Files: Yes

Any feed back to help me out with speeding my website https://femascu.net/

Thanks in advance
[image]

[image]

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: If you could post additional information requested Dec 27, 2022 at 18:03 we could complete our Complimentary server workload tuning analysis for you and provide some suggestions to improve your query completion speed. Thank you.  View profile for contact info.

Answer (score 0):

As google showing follows those steps:

1. Optimise Images.
2. Remove unuse CSS/JS or any other static files.
3. Use custom profiler to debug your own code on local so you will know which part of code taking how much time.

I think major concern is about TTFB, your server is taking so much time so use OPCache and optimise your server. Use FPC, check all cache are enable or not. Do not use helper/object manager directly in phtml file. Increase RAM may be help of your server.

Answer (score 0):

GTMETRIX.COM today reports

Analysis Error
The SSL certificate being used on this website was issued for another website's address

when trying to get analysis for https://www.femascu.net

myip.ms  reporting indicates this is a DEDICATED Server which is good for your Ranked # 708,556 worldwide rank.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see some backend options in production mode so first change **production mode to developer mode** and then configure the settings. I mentioned it below.

1. Disable Use Flat Catalog Category and Use Flat Catalog Product options.
   ==> Go to Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Storefront -> Use Flat Catalog Category && Use Flat Catalog Product -> No -> Save Config.
2. Enable JS Bundling
   ==> Go to Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> JavaScript Settings -> Enable JavaScript Bundling -> Yes -> Save Config.
3. Inspect Third-Party Extensions
   ==> Remove unused module from the site.
4. Minify CSS and JavaScript
   ==> Go to Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Minify JavaScript Files && Minify CSS Files -> Yes -> Save Config.
   After that Flush Cache on System -> Cache Management -> Flush Magento Cache.
5. Enable GZIP Compression
   Note : You can Enable GZIP Compression using .htaccess file.
6. Integrate Content Delivery Network
   ==> Go to Store -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Base URLs -> Base URL for Static View Files -> Base URL for User Media Files -> Save Config.

   1. On the Base URL for Static View Files field, enter the URL of CDN where static view files are stored.
   2. In the Base URL for User Media Files field, enter the URL of CDN where JavaScript files.
      When complete, click Save Config.
7. Enable Elastic Search
   ==> Go to Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Catalog → Catalog → Catalog Search -> Search Engine -> Elasticsearch -> Save config.
8. Implement Varnish Cache
   ==> Go to Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Full Page Cache -> Caching Application -> Varnish Caching -> Varnish Configuration -> Configure details -> Save config.
9. Clean Database Logs

Note : Set particular time on New Messages Lifetime to automatically clean the old log files.
==> Stores -> Configuration Advanced -> System -> MySQL Message Queue Cleanup -> New Messages Lifetime -> Save Config.

10. Re-index Products on Your Store
    Note : Please reindex using command line.
11. Optimize Product Images
    Note : Large images size is impacts on site speed That's why you need to ensure your images are properly optimized and have a good ratio between quality and size.

After all the changes are done go to **production mode** again.